# can I copy SSL certificates and ca

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

I am testing ssl for rabbitmq locally. This setup consists of sever and client. I followed the instruction [RabbitMQ SSL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html). I created ca, server, client certificates and keys. Everything worked.

But when I sent all those files to a colleague, who uses ubuntu, it didn't work for him. Whatever we tried connection between server and client didn't happen.
Although when we checked certificates on server and client using OpenSSL `s_client` and `s_server` to check that secure link can be established, connection was successful.

As described here https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

```
   openssl s_server -accept 8443 -cert server/cert.pem -key server/key.pem -CAfile testca/cacert.pem

   openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -cert client/cert.pem -key client/key.pem -CAfile testca/cacert.pem
```

So my question is whether those keys and certificates can be just copied from OS to OS. Namely can CA be copied or should it be generated on every os separately?

Comment: Most certificates are tagged to the hostname of the computer for which they are used.  Which means you can't just copy them to another server, you should generate one for each server.

Answer (score 0):

I copy cacerts from os to os. But I generate keystore individually for each server because it is used to authenticate itself.

Comment: so you generate only server certificate? what about client? is it possible to generate several server certificates using same cacert?